# How can extend AutoComplete to change dataSource and dataTextField dynamically in kendo?

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, extend, datatextfield

how change datasource and dataTextField  with extent autocomplete kendo when user enter number or text ? for example. I want when user enter id show name in dropdown list and when enter name show name .

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filtering event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#events-filtering), check the incoming filter, and based on its type, programmatically [filter the dataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter):

[Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OfIre)